# OSError: [Errno 45] Operation not supported: '/home/samuelchin' - Mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am trying to run this code: https://github.com/jkschin/svhn .. 
 when I run svn_train.py I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "svhn_train.py", line 93, in
<module>
    tf.app.run()   File "/Users/n/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))   File "svhn_train.py", line 88, in main
    gfile.MakeDirs(FLAGS.train_dir)   File "/Users/n/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/gfile.py",
line 295, in MakeDirs
    os.makedirs(path, mode)   File "/Users/n/anaconda/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)    File "/Users/n/anaconda/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)   File "/Users/n/anaconda/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs

   makedirs(head, mode)   File "/Users/aljaafn/anaconda/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs

   mkdir(name, mode) OSError: [Errno 45] Operation not supported: '/home/samuelchin'
```

The code is built in Python & Tensorflow to run and train a model on  the SVHN data.

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Without access to the code, it's really hard to tell.  Which directory is it trying to create?  Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: All the files are in the link : https://github.com/jkschin/svhn

Comment: Looks like it's trying to create `/home/samuelchin` which of course it neither should nor should want to.  On OSX, the home directories of users are in `/Users` (not `/home`, which is standard on Linux), but you definitely do not want user code to try to create new directories there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://github.com/jkschin/svhn/blob/master/svhn_flags.py#L7 hardcodes the author's local home directory, which is definitely not portable.  Like the README says, you need to be able to hack the code in order to get it to work.

Comment: is this an answer?  Its not really making sense to me, could you explain?  Thanks

Comment: It tells you what's wrong, and broadly how to fix it; but I have not tried it, and there may be additional kinks down the road. In any event, fixing it requires some familiarity with Python and the underlying platform. Maybe bug the author of the code if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @conor909 Try `base_dir = '.'` and probably run the code in a directory you have created for this purpose. Be prepared to solve similar problems down the line (I haven't really looked, and it's a long time since I wrote the answer above).

Comment: ... Though the README says the code is experimental and unmaintained.

Comment: My issue is I don't know anything about python.  Im developing a node.js app and I accidentally ran `export HOME=/` in my terminal, so now git and other cli's dont work properly, I dont know what the HOME variable was previously

Comment: Just log out and back in again.

Comment: ah!  ..really appreciate the help!